# orientdb: how to fully shutdown down a memory database (Java/Scala API)

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to write some unit test utilities for an orientDB client in scala.

The following is intended to take a function to operate on a DB, and it should wrap the function with code to create and destroy the DB for a single unit test.

However, there doesn't see to be much good documentation on how to clean up a memory DB (and looking at many open source projects, people seem to simply just leak databases and create new ones on a new port).

Simply calling db.close leaves the DB listening to a port and subsequent tests fail. Calling db.drop seems to work, but only if the func succeeded in adding data to the DB.

So, what cleanup is required in the finally clause?

```
  @Test
  def fTest2(): Unit = {


    def withJSONDBLoan(func: ODatabaseDocumentTx => Unit) : Unit = {
      val db: ODatabaseDocumentTx = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("memory:jsondb")
      db.create()
      try {

        func(db)

      } finally {
        if (!db.isClosed){
          db.close   // Nope. DB is leaked.
        }
        // db.drop seems to close the DB but can't
        // see when to safely call this.
      }
    }


    val query1 = "insert into ouser set name='test',password='test', status='ACTIVE'"
    withJSONDBLoan { db =>
      db.command(new OCommandSQL(query1)).execute[ODocument]()
    }

    // Fails at create because DB already exists.
    val query2 = "insert into ouser set name='test2',password='test2', status='ACTIVE'"
    withJSONDBLoan { db =>
      db.command(new OCommandSQL(query2)).execute[ODocument]()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it worked for me.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sure. It works because the database is leaked. I'll update the question with a failing query.